# If $A$ is finite and $f: A \rightarrow A$, $f$ is injective iff $\text{ran}f = A$: How Simple is My Proof Allowed to Be?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

**Synopsis**

This exercise seems so obvious that I don't know how to put it into words. A simple diagram shows this to be true. But I've tried to write down a proof anyways, and I was wondering if any of you would be willing to check that its acceptable. In other words, if you were a teacher, would you accept my proof?

**Exercise**

Assume that $A$ is finite and $f: A \rightarrow A $. Show that $f$ is one-to-one iff $\text{ran}f = A$.

**Proof**

Suppose that $f: A \rightarrow A$ is one-to-one. Then every element in $A$ must be mapped to some other unique element in $A$. Since $A$ is finite, this implies that $\text{ran}f = A$. Now suppose $\text{ran}f = A$. Then by the pigeonhole principle, in order for $f$ to be a function, $f$ must be injective.

Comment: This depends on how much information you already have available about finite sets. For example, if I tried to prove the same result for infinite sets by just replacing "Since $A$ is finite" with "Since $A$ is infinite", something must be wrong (because the result is false for infinite sets). But what exactly is wrong? Which step of the "proof" won't work? Your proof should make it clear exactly how finiteness is used to justify what you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one's fine, but for the second one, being more precise is a better option.

Assume for the other way that $\text{ran} ~ f =A$. As $A$ is finite, we can let $|A|=n$. Suppose there is a $x \in A$ such that there are $x_1,x_2 \in A$, $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=x$. Then there are $n-2$ elements in the domain, while there are $n-1$ in the range, and as the image of of an element is unique, by the pigeonhole principle, there must be at least one element in $A$ which does not possess a pre-image, contradicting our assumption that $\text{ran} f = A$

Comment: Thank you! I agree that this is more clear.

Comment: Very happy to help :)